# How to remove incorrect boxes in YOLO?

Tags: yolo, darknet

I use YOLOv2 on Darknet in Window. I trained a image. I thought YOLOv2 uses NMS algorithm.
But my result was like this.

Where do I put some code for removing incorrect boxes?

[image]

Comment: Which repository do you use?

Comment: @gameon67 I used this. https://github.com/unsky/yolo-for-windows-v2

Comment: try this repo maybe? https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

Comment: @gameon67 Is there a difference between them??

Comment: Of course. As far as I know, this repo github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet is the most popular one